# filter object array with other object array - React Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm getting data from the server and saving it in 2 different states so one will show all the data received and the other one will show it as pagination.

The array type is:

```
type ArrayType = {
  name:string;
  id:number;
  link:string;
}
```

Now the first array has over 200 objects inside of it, while the second array has only 15 objects inside of it.

I'm trying to loop and filter it but it returns the lasts objects + the same last Objects:

```html
interface ComponentState {
  total?: ArrayType[];
  few?: ArrayType[];
}

const Component = () => {
  const isMounted = useRef(true);
  const [state, setState] = useState<ComponentState>({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const updateState = async () => {
      const res = await fetch(FetchUrl);
      const data = await res.json();
      setState((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        total: data,
        few: data.slice(0, 10),
      }));
    };

    if (isMounted.current) updateState();

    return () => {
      isMounted.current = false;
    };
  }, []);
};
```

Now When I want to update The state.few I'm trying to do:

```html
const onButtonClick = () => {
    setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      few: [
        ...state.few!,
        ...state.total!.filter((item) =>
          state.few!.filter((prevItem) => prevItem !== item)
        ).slice(0,10),
      ],
    }));
  };

  console.log(state.few);

  return <button onClick={onButtonClick}></button>;
```

And I keep getting the first 10 items of state.total instead of the next 10 items in the list

Comment: Please describe in more detail what you want to implement. Generally (since `few` can be deduced from `total`) it is not a good idea to store the `few` array at all. It seems like you want to add the next 10 elements from `total` to `few`, so `few` holds 20 elements after the first click. Is that correct? Or do you want to show the next page, so `few` had elements 0-9 before the click and now holds elements 10-19?

Comment: I want it to holds 20 elements. and each click would add more 10 elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React you should not store variables that can be calculated from the state in another state.

So what's the information you need to implement a 'load more' button?

- all the list elements
- the index up to which you want to render

These are your state variables. Which items to render can be calculated from those.

So I would implement your component as follows:

```
const Component = ()=> {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [showN, setShowN] = useState(10);

  // calculate elements to render from state
  const toRender = items.slice(0, showN);

  useEffect(()=>{
    // your isMounted ref does not work. You need to check if the component is mounted before setting the state, not before firing the async function 
    let stillMounted = true;
    const updateState = async () => {
      const res = await fetch(FetchUrl);
      const data = await res.json();
      // check if still mounted
      if(!stillMounted) return;
      setItems(data);
      };
    updateState();
    // on unmount, this function will be called, preventing a state update on an unmounted component
    return ()=>stillMounted = false;
  }, []);
  
  // just update the showN state when the button is clicked
  const onButtonClick = ()=>{
    setShowN(before=>before + 10);
  }
  // return something
}
```